# Chain rule for functions with two and three variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $F(x,y)=f(x,y,g(x,y))$.
>
> (i) Find $DF$ in terms of the partials of $f$ and $g$.
>
> (ii) If $F(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y)$, find $D_1g$ and $D_2g$ in terms of the partials of $f$.

So I apply the chain rule. Let $p(x,y)=(x,y,g(x,y))$. Then $DF(x,y)=Df(p(x,y))\cdot Dp(x,y)$. So $Df(p(x,y))$ is a $1\times 3$ matrix, with elements $D_if(x,y,g(x,y))$ for $i=1,2,3$. Also, $Dp(x,y)$ is a $3\times 2$ matrix, with elements in the top row being $1,0$ (partial derivatives of $x$), the second row being $0,1$ (partial derivatives of $y$), and the bottom row being $D_1g(x,y)$ and $D_2g(x,y)$.

For part (ii), since $F(x,y)=0$, we have $DF(x,y)=0$. So we can just solve for $D_1g(x,y)$ and $D_2g(x,y)$ to get $D_ig(x,y)=-\dfrac{D_if(x,y,g(x,y))}{D_3f(x,y,g(x,y))}$ for $i=1,2$.

Is this solid reasoning using the chain rule?

Comment: Looks like everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In simple cases like this one, it is not necessary to use matrix multiplication. One can directly trace the dependency of $F$ on each variable. Let $z$ denote the third argument of $f$. Then
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y,g(x,y)) = f_x(x,y,g(x,y))+f_z(x,y,g(x,y))g_x(x,y)$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y,g(x,y)) = f_y(x,y,g(x,y))+f_z(x,y,g(x,y))g_y(x,y)$$
If $F$ is constant, then both expressions on the right  are zero, which gives 
$$
g_x(x,y) = -\frac{f_x(x,y,g(x,y))}{f_z(x,y,g(x,y))}, \quad
g_xy(x,y) = -\frac{f_y(x,y,g(x,y))}{f_z(x,y,g(x,y))}
$$